# Extracting array product from neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I'm training a neural network which is meant to model a collection of functions that map $N$-dimensional vectors to scalars. At this point, I have built up several layers which manipulate the input vectors into a desired form; call this vector $\vec{a}$. In the final step, I want the neural network to output the product of each of these elements, i.e.,

$$\prod_{j=1}^{N}a_{j}$$

Is there a single layer which can implement this step? Essentially, what I need is a multiplicative analog of `SummationLayer[]`.

EDIT: It's been suggested that I try using `ThreadingLayer[Times]` to extract the product. I've tried putting this as the final layer in `NetChain[]` and gotten the following output:

> NetChain::indmultiport: The third layer has an indeterminate number of input ports. Please ensure it is connected to at least one other layer or manually specify its input ports using "Inputs" -> {...}.

Specifying the inputs seems to control the number of input arrays upon which elementwise multiplication is performed. I'm not sure how to deal with this error.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a multiplicative analog of `TotalLayer` (element-wise summation for a list of arrays), or of `SummationLayer` (= overall total of all elements in input)?

Comment: `SummationLayer` - thanks for catching that, I will correct the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
times = ThreadingLayer[Times];
times[Range[5]]

Out[1]= 120.
```

Does this work for you?

EDIT: Based on the clarification re: `SummationLayer` vs `TotalLayer`, the documentation for `SummationLayer` again provides us with a hint:

> SummationLayer[] is equivalent to AggregationLayer[Total,All]:

as such, we can use this instead:

```
times = AggregationLayer[Times, All]
times[Range[5]]

Out[1] = 120.
```

Comment: I tried this but encountered an error when incorporating that into NetChain - I'll add more details in an edit.

Comment: It should be noted that under "Properties & relations" there is an example stating that `TotalLayer` is equivalent to `ThreadingLayer[Plus]`, so this is indeed the analogue for multiplication as requested in the original question.